# passing file path as argument in shellexecute

Tags: c++, shellexecute, createprocess

i want my other c++ program to be run from another file so i am using shell execute. Mu code is :

```
#pragma comment(lib,"shell32.lib")  
#include "windows.h"
#include<Shellapi.h>

#include<stdio.h>
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;

class spwan{
public:
    //char szPath[] = "";
    void run(char path[]);
};

void spwan::run(char szPath[]){
HINSTANCE ShellExecute(HWND,  "open", szPath,"","",SW_SHOW);    
    cout<<"program executed";
}

int main ()
{
 spwan s;
 s.run("path to the file");
}
```

But i am having problem like expected a type specifier with "open" and i am not able to define the path using szPath. Anyhelp.

errors more specifically are:
its giving me error for line : HINSTANCE ShellExecute(HWND, "open", szPath,"","",SW_SHOW); as syntax error : 'string'

when i am giving path like this :- C:\Users\saira\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Projects\phase_1_solver\Debug\phase_1_solver.exe its giving errors like : warning C4129: 's' : unrecognized character escape sequence warning C4129: 'D' : unrecognized character escape sequence

Comment: Please tell us what is wrong. Compiler error? Runtime failure? And provide the exact message. Also, it is spelled `spawn`. No need to pass a window handle here. Pass `0`. Also no need to pass a verb, pass `NULL`. Pass `NULL` rather than `""` for the other two parameters also.

Comment: This really boils down to how to properly call a function, and if you can't do that, I strongly suggest not getting into the Windows API.

Comment: the main thing i want to know is how can i use the path as an argument.

Comment: You are already using it as an argument. I can't understand why you won't tell us what is wrong? You ask for help, but won't reveal the details. I mean, I guess that problem is that `ShellExecute` is actually `ShellExecuteW` and expects wide strings. But if you won't tell us the error, that would just be a wild guess.

Comment: its giving me error for line : HINSTANCE ShellExecute(HWND,  "open", szPath,"","",SW_SHOW);  as syntax error : 'string'

Comment: That should appear in the question rather than in comments.

Comment: when i am giving path like this :- C:\Users\saira\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Projects\phase_1_solver\Debug\phase_1_solver.exe  
its giving errors like :
warning C4129: 's' : unrecognized character escape sequence
warning C4129: 'D' : unrecognized character escape sequence

Comment: i am really for trouble

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your code you have:

```
HINSTANCE ShellExecute(HWND,  "open", szPath,"","",SW_SHOW);
```

That is a declaration of a function. I presume that you actually meant to call the function:

```
HINSTANCE retval = ShellExecute(HWND,  "open", szPath,"","",SW_SHOW);
```

Now, that won't compile either. Since `HWND` is a type. I think you need:

```
HINSTANCE retval = ShellExecute(0, "open", szPath, NULL, NULL, SW_SHOW);
```

What's more, there's no need to actually specify a verb. The default verb for a path will suffice.

```
HINSTANCE retval = ShellExecute(0, NULL, szPath, NULL, NULL, SW_SHOW);
```

And it sounds as though you are passing strings like this:

```
s.run("C:\Users\saira\...\phase_1_solver.exe");
```

That's not good because the backslash is used as the escape character in C++. So you need to escape it:

```
s.run("C:\\Users\\saira\\...\\phase_1_solver.exe");
```

If you are not going to test the return value then you can simply write:

```
ShellExecute(0, NULL, szPath, NULL, NULL, SW_SHOW);
```

If you do want to check for errors on return from `ShellExecute`, then `ShellExecute` is a bad function to call. Its error handling is particularly weak. Use `ShellExecuteEx` instead. Raymond Chen discusses the error handling of `ShellExecute` in [Why does ShellExecute return SE_ERR_ACCESSDENIED for nearly everything?](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2012/10/18/10360604.aspx)

Comment: what should i do for the escape character sequence warning

Comment: and what is this now i mean i know that there is type mismatch but what kind of casting i need to do for this. error C2664: 'ShellExecuteW' : cannot convert parameter 2 from 'const char [5]' to 'LPCWSTR'
1>          Types pointed to are unrelated; conversion requires reinterpret_cast, C-style cast or function-style cast

Comment: Two ways to solve that. Either call `ShellExecuteA` and stick to ANSI charset. Other way to achieve that is to switch project options to MBCS. Or you can use Unicode. Which do you want to do?

Comment: OK, I guessed as much. Thanks for listening and providing all the extra info I asked for. Well done!